# Leon: how to use custom `==` operator?

Tags: scala, leon

While working with leon and rationals, I encountered the following issue: the verification of the `inverse1` function gives a counter-example but it doesn't make much sense, while `inverse2` verifies.

```
import leon.lang._

case class Rational (n: BigInt, d: BigInt) {

  def +(that: Rational): Rational = {
    require(isRational && that.isRational)
    Rational(n * that.d + that.n * d, d * that.d)
  } ensuring { _.isRational }

  def *(that: Rational): Rational = {
    require(isRational && that.isRational)
    Rational(n * that.n, d * that.d)
  } ensuring { _.isRational }

  def <=(that: Rational): Boolean = {
    require(isRational && that.isRational)
    if (that.d * d > 0)
      n * that.d <= d * that.n
    else
      n * that.d >= d * that.n
  }

  def ==(that: Rational): Boolean = {
    require(isRational && that.isRational)
    //that <= this && this <= that
    true // for testing purpose of course!
  }

  // fails to verify
  def inverse1: Rational = {
    require(isRational && nonZero)
    Rational(d, n)
  }.ensuring { res => res.isRational && res.nonZero && res * this == Rational(1, 1) }

  // verifies
  def inverse2: Rational = {
    require(isRational && nonZero)
    Rational(d, n)
  }.ensuring { res => res.isRational && res.nonZero /*&& res * this == Rational(1, 1)*/ }

  def isRational = !(d == 0)
  def nonZero = n != 0

}
```

The counter example leon gives me is this:

```
[  Info  ]  - Now considering 'postcondition' VC for Rational$inverse1 @33:16...
[ Error  ]  => INVALID
[ Error  ] Found counter-example:
[ Error  ]   $this -> Rational(-2, -2)
```

But it makes no sense mathematically speaking.

I was expecting this code to call the `==` operator I've defined but since this one always returns `true` and the function doesn't verify, I'm inclined to think otherwise...

Could someone indicate what's wrong with this program or my understanding of Scala/leon? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Leon, but scala compiler desugars `==` to an `.equals` call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not possible. As you can see [here](https://github.com/epfl-lara/leon/blob/v3.0/src/main/scala/leon/frontends/scalac/CodeExtraction.scala#L1334) and [here](https://github.com/epfl-lara/leon/blob/v3.0/src/main/scala/leon/frontends/scalac/ASTExtractors.scala#L732) in the source, `==` is not treated by Leon as an ordinary method call, but it's turned into a special AST node called `Equals`.

But there's a simple fix: Just call your equality `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: Thanks Samuel. I was hoping for a different answer but at least now I know why it behaves that way.